# How can I call prototype child method from parent

Tags: javascript, prototype

I want to call child object method form prototype object:

```
function Hamster() {
    this.sleep = function(){
      console.log('sleep');
    }
}

Hamster.prototype = new function(){

    var _self = this;

    this.test = function(){
      this.sleep();
      //_self.sleep(); //not working
    }
}

lazy = new Hamster();
lazy.test();
```

Why when I use `this.sleep()` everything works fine, but when I use `_self.sleep()` (`_self` variable has `this` value) I get error? Why `_self` and `this` inside the `test()` function are not same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write it with a function which returns the two things, letting us compare them more easily

```
function Constructor() {}

Constructor.prototype = new function () {
    var foo = this;
    this.bar = function () {
        return {"this": this, "foo": foo};
    };
};

var instance = new Constructor(),
    o = instance.bar();
```

And now test what we've got

```
o.this === instance; // true
o.foo === instance; // fase
// so what is o.foo ?
o.foo === Constructor.prototype; // true
```

What does this tell us?

- When we invoke a method from `instance`, `this` refers to that instance
- When we invoke a function with `new`, then `this` refers to a new object instance created by the `new`; in this case it is the object we've then set as the *prototype* for `Constructor`

When are these references set?

- The `this` in `instance.bar` is only set when `instance.bar` is actually invoked
- The `this` from the `new function () { ... }`  is set immediately as it is created and does not change after that (you've basically used an *IIFE* ), it is also what is returned by the `new` so what the `Constructor.prototype` gets set to in this example

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What you can advice me in this case: http://jsbin.com/calatoqimeda/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

The `this` reference stored in `self` is different from the `this` reference you call inside the anonymous function you assigned to `test()`. The point is that the `this` scope of the function you're creating and assigning to `Hamster.prototype` is an empty object. It's so because you used the `new` keyword.

```
Hamster.prototype = new function(){

    //Stores the reference to the empty object that's the scope of the anonymous 
    //function because it was called using the new keyword.
    var _self = this; 

    this.test = function(){
      //Works because the this keyword is a reference to Hamster.
      this.sleep(); 

      //Does not work because the empty object doesn't have a sleep method.
      //_self.sleep(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: actually, when i concole.log(_self), it shows the function itself, not an empty object.

Comment: "It's so because you used the `new` keyword."  Exactly.  And unless you know what you're doing and why, I would recommend never doing `new function() {...}`.  Use an IIFE if you need a closure scope.

Comment: @dandavis: I get the behavior described by William.

Comment: @dandavis When you call a function using the "new" keyword, the this reference to that function is an empty object. By the time you console.log() it, the object has already been modified.

Answer (score 1):

You're confused about how prototypes work.

You probably want nothing more than

```
Hamster.prototype = {
    test: function() {
        this.sleep();
    }
};
```

What you are doing is creating a new object for the prototype. The `_self` variable you are setting is not pointing to the `this` of individual Hamster objects, but rather to the `this` of the new prototype object you are creating, which is lost to the world.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I have used this method previously, but in this case i can't set prototype of prototype. But when i use object, which i get from constructor function I can set prototype for this function. What you can advice me in this case: http://jsbin.com/takakoxaquki/1/edit

Comment: actually, when i concole.log(_self), it shows the function itself, not a prototype object.

Comment: That's odd. `Hamster.prototype=new function() { var _self = this; console.log(_self); };` displays `Object {}`.

Comment: I think your JSBin is not really well-considered.  What would happen if I created a second Hamster instance with a different sleep function, and then clicked the button?  What would you expect `_self` to represent?  One of the hamsters?  Somehow both of them?  Something else?  In fact, it represents the prototype object itself, but you seem to be looking for it to be more.

Answer (score 0):

_self is a local variable outside the anonymous function you defined and you did not pass it through so its not defined inside

Comment: It's inside a closure, so the inner function **can** see _self.